# How to prevent double md5-ing of password field on update form?

Tags: php, passwords, md5

On my user info update form, i let users update the pass along with other things.  If they don't want to update the password in the form, they leave it blank, as in the field is left empty.  On the process page, if the field is blank i insert their existing password from the db (its md5) and if they changed it i want the new password in.  Below is what i am using to try and accomplish that, but it is double md5-ing no matter what:

```
      if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

$newpass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$newpass = md5($_POST['password']);

    }

    // If $dob is empty
    if (empty($newpass)) {

    $newpass = "$passis"; //$passis = the password stored in db which is md5
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to wager that `if (empty($newpass))` is never true.

Comment: Why are you assigning `$newpass` that often? Why do you even want to fill that with the password from the database? If one doesn't want to update the password, leave it empty and just don't update it

Comment: @poke yeah but what if they want to update it, how would i know??

Comment: If the field they submitted is empty, they don't want to update it, so don't do it. If there is something in there, update it. No need to put the value from the database into anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little reworking of your code:

```
  $newpass = $_POST['password'];

  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $newpass = mysql_escape_string($newpass);
  }

  if(empty($newpass)) {
    $newpass = "$passis"; //$passis = existing md5'd password already stored in db
  }
  else {
    $newpass = md5($newpass); //$newpass = newly provided password needs to be md5'd before updating db
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`$newpass` will never be empty because md5 converts the empty string to a hash. So this condition will not work:  `if (empty($newpass)) {`

Instead you have to do

```
 if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
```

**UPDATE**

```
 if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

$newpass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$newpass = md5($_POST['password']);

}

// If $dob is empty
if (empty($_POST['password'])) { 
   $newpass = "$passis"; //$passis = the password stored in db which is md5
}
```

Comment: Hey... i still get the same issue:  this is what i am doing:   if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
 
  $_POST['password'] = $passis;

}

Comment: yeah because the `$_POST`password should be only used in the condition, not for assigning *dont do this:* `$_POST['password'] = $passis;`, *you have to do this:* `$newpass = $passis;` check out my answer update

Answer (score 1):

You code is strange because it performes md5 only if the magic_quotes_gpc directive is set.
Another think is that the md5 of the empty string is not the empty string.

Here is a code that should work nicer:

```
$newpass = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
if ($newpass=='') {
  $newpass = $passis; // $passis = the password stored in db which is md5
} else {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $newpass = stripslashes($newpass); // take off slashes added by PHP if any
  $newpass = md5($newpass);
}
```